# Deploy Excel or Office JavaScript add-ins with Apache

Tags: excel, office-js

Is it possible to deploy the new JavaScript add-ins as simple static files using something like Apache?  The tutorials suggest ISS or Node.

The add-in that I have in mind has zero interactions with the web, only with the spreadsheet itself.

I would ideally like to just be able to reference the files with file:// URLs but that would be too easy.

Note that I am not talking about VBA, VSTO, C#.Net.  Those are all easy.  I am talking about the newest, most obtuse technology.

Why suffer the pain?  Because Microsoft hates VBA.  It is slowly degrading.  And eventually I will have to move on.  They are fools, because VBA is their secret sauce, but so be it.

Comment: "It is slowly degrading" - is it though?  Sure it's not getting *better*, but it's going to be around for a long time yet. ISS (IIS?)/Node are just web servers so there seems no reason why Apache wouldn't also work.  Might help if you could be a little more specific though - maybe a link or two to the tutorials you're referencing?

Comment: An example of the degredation of VBA is the ribbon interface.  No easy way to store the ribbon handle across error resets. They did not even bother to add Application.Ribbon.   Another is that VBA cannot utilize the task pane, say with a dialog.  Slowly might mean many years, but MS hate VBA which is not good.

Comment: Node.js is much more than a web server, it is a development platform.  Likewise IIS with .Net.  What I want to know is whether they can be delivered as simple static files that are uploaded.  Should be the case, but his is horribly messy.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can host the web application part of an Office Add-in on an Apache server.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Is it just static data or does it need active content, something running, probably not in PHP?  Do you have any references?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Apache, but I believe it can host any kind of content including static and dynamic. The main site seem to be https://httpd.apache.org/.

Comment: Yes of course plugins can support anything.  But I just use a LAMP provider and so cannot add arbitrary plug ins.